# connecting to Altlas or localhost

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, localhost, mongodb-atlas

I can connect to localhost or Atlas, but when I try to use the || it breaks. I have to specify 'dbName' when connecting to Atlas,but it breaks my localhost.

this code works for localhost:

```
mongoose.connect( process.env.LOCAL );
mongoose.connection.on("open", function (ref) {
  console.log("Connected to mongo server.");
});
mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) { console.log(err) });
```

and this code works for my Atlas:

```
mongoose.connect( process.env.ATLAS_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, dbName: 'wwatlasDB' });
mongoose.connection.on("open", function (ref) {
  console.log("Connected to mongo server.");
});
mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) { console.log(err) });
```

but when I try:

```
mongoose.connect( process.env.LOCAL || process.env.ATLAS_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, dbName: 'wwatlasDB' });
```

it fails. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The easy way is just to check that you have current `env` before `connect`, as for example:

```
if(process.env.LOCAL) {
 mongoose.connect( process.env.LOCAL );
} else {
 mongoose.connect( process.env.ATLAS_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, dbName: 'wwatlasDB' } );
}
mongoose.connection.on("open", function (ref) {
 console.log("Connected to mongo server.");
});
mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) { console.log(err) });
```

Comment: hmm, that does not work. The problem seems to be when I specify dbName (which is required to connect to Atlas) my local does not work. Is there a way to ignore that logic when connecting locally?

Answer (score 0):

```
mongoose.connect( process.env.ATLAS_URI, { useNewUrlParser: true, dbName: 'wwatlasDB' });
mongoose.connection.on("open", function (ref) {
  console.log("Connected to mongo server.");
});
mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) { console.log(err) });
```

This seems to connect locally as well!